# Deployment using Composer replacing old style install but issues with legacy Drush

Tags: drush

I took a Drupal project that was created awhile back via downloading a tar file and recreated it on a local via composer with drupal-project.

The recommended files were committed to git (i.e. no contributed modules, etc.) and cloned on the server. The composer install was clean.

At the point of doing a `$ drush sqlc` to load the database, it became evident that there was an issue - Drush error message below. I believe the issue is that Drush was already installed.

`$ which drush` outputs `/home/me/.composer/vendor/bin/drush`.

The error message when I attempt to run `drush sqlc` or `drush status` from the project, even with `--root`, is the following.

> PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/../../load.environment.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
>       PHP Stack trace:
>       PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/drush/drush/drush:0
>       PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4
>       PHP   3. include_once() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:56
>       PHP   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit6220513682b217c143f76d07878222a3::getLoader() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/autoload.php:7
>       PHP   5. composerRequire6220513682b217c143f76d07878222a3() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:60
>       PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/../../load.environment.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
>       PHP Stack trace:
>       PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/drush/drush/drush:0
>       PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4
>       PHP   3. include_once() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:56
>       PHP   4. ComposerAutoloaderInit6220513682b217c143f76d07878222a3::getLoader() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/autoload.php:7
>       PHP   5. composerRequire6220513682b217c143f76d07878222a3() /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:60

In addition to Drush being in both `~/.composer/vendor` and `<root>/vendor`, I note that `~/.composer` contains

```
autoload.php
composer
phpdocumentor
phpunit
symfony
bin
doctrine
phpspec
sebastian
```

How do I go about cleaning this up so that the project root is the sole repository of these files and Drush can find what it's looking for?

Comment: Have you installed Drush Launcher? https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jaypan commented, globally you only need the Drush Launcher as phar file. And remove the old globally installed Drush version, this install method via `composer global require` is no longer supported. If you still need a legacy Drush version for other Drupal sites, download it the same way as phar file, see http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install. Which then can act as launcher by the way, so you don't need the Drush Launcher in this case.

Comment: Not to forget to simply call the local Drush directly: `$ cd path/to/drupal-project && vendor/drush/drush/drush sql-dump > test.sql`.

Comment: I removed the original drush that was not in the Drupal project. I installed the drush launcher (and renamed drush.phar to drush and did a chmod +x as instructed) in /usr/local/bin. When I run drush with or without the path, from within the Drupal site folder, I get the following (note the load.environment.php path with ../.. in the middle of it)

Comment: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/../../load.environment.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/../../load.environment.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/drupal/d8/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Answer (score 1):

If you need global drush for legacy sites, and local drush for [drupal-composer](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) projects, then this may work for you.

I keep a copy of drush from Github, and fetch and checkout the latest 8.X.Y tag periodically.  This executable is on my bash path.

For drupal-composer projects, I use [direnv](https://direnv.net/), and then put the following in my .envrc

```
PATH_add /home/mpdonadio/my-drupal-site/vendor/bin
```

Then when you cd into that directory, the vendor/bin for that project gets prepended to PS1, and that version of drush gets used.  This lets me use Drush 9 for newer projects, and when combined with [webflo/drupal-core-strict](https://github.com/webflo/drupal-core-strict) and [drupal-core-require-dev](https://github.com/webflo/drupal-core-require-dev) you can avoid most dependency problems.

This approach also allows better control of [drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/), phpunit, and other dev executables; they gets added to the path and will pull in the same dependencies, and avoid update issues.

Comment: The final piece was copying load.environment.php to the project root. Not certain how it came to not be there, but putting it there resolved that error.